# Check if an element contains a css class in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

There are multiple tabs like this:

```
 <Menu.Item className="tab-title tab-multiple" key="key">
     <p className="tab-title-text">
         Tab title
        <span className="items-counter">{showText}</span>
      </p>
 </Menu.Item>
```

the one that is the active/selected one, beside of its original class (`tab-title tab-multiple`) it also has `active` and its class looks like this: `active tab-title tab-multiple`

I want to show that  element only if the class contains "active".

Is there a way to do this in React? Without taking in account onClick.

Tried with a ternary but it seems it does not work:

```
{element.classList.contains('active') ? (
  <span className="items-counter">{showText}</span>
 ) : (<></>)}
```

Comment: What is your element in your code ? Can you provide a reproductible example ?

Comment: I don't think it can be reproduced here. What I want is to show that span only if Menu.Item containts "active" in its css class

Comment: There's no way to help you without knowing what your code is doing. It seems weird that you would have to query the dom nodes in a react application. You can probably fix this problem with react itself or with css

Comment: Yes, you can add [mcve]s for React code here: Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you don't have to do that in React because you drive the classes on the element from state information in your component, and so you just look at that state information rather than looking at the class list. Your best bet by far is to do that, rather than accessing the DOM class list later.

---

If the `active` class is being added by something outside the React realm that's operating directly on the DOM element, you'll have to use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) so you can access the DOM element.

To create the ref:

```
const ref = React.createRef();
```

To connect it to your React element, you add the `ref` property;

```
<Menu.Item className="tab-title tab-multiple" key="key" ref={ref}>
```

Then when you need to know, you check the `current` property on the ref:

```
if (ref.current && ref.current.classList.contains("active")) {
    // ...
}
```

**Beware** that if you do that during a call to `render` (on a class component) or to your functional component's function, on the first call the ref will be `null` and on subsequent calls it'll always refer to the element for the previous version of the component. That element will probably get reused, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

React is driven by the data model (props & state). Use whatever data property you use to assign the `active` class name, to also hide/show the contents.

Another option is to use CSS:

```css
.items-counter {
  color: red;
}

.tab-title:not(.active) .items-counter {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-title tab-multiple" key="key">
  <p class="tab-title-text">
    Tab title
    <span class="items-counter">Not Active</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="tab-title tab-multiple active" key="key">
  <p class="tab-title-text">
    Tab title
    <span class="items-counter">Active</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an indicator, that maintains the active class.

```
let className ="";
if(isActive)
   {
      className = className +" active"; // props.isActive in case of child component
   }
```

Now that you have added the className based on the flag.
instead of checking for,

```
if(element.classList.contains('active'))
```

you can check for,

```
if(isActive)
```

This is applicable for subcomponents also, where you read the isActive flag through props.